# How do I install Ubuntu on a Meego pad t01

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, kubuntu

This Christmas I received a MeeGo Pad T01 as a present and have been checking around the inter-webs for a Ubuntu/Linux installation guide without success.

So my question is fairly self explanatory how do I install Ubuntu on this device?

any flavour will do

If possible a step by step guide to follow would be great especially for anyone coming here in the future.

btw managed to bring up the bios with F7 will add more info as I get it

Answer (score 4):

According to [2015 latest MeeGoPad Intel Quad Core Z3735Fwindows mini pc dongle TV dongle windows8.1 Android Ubuntu set top box compute stick](http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/2015-latest-Meegopad-Intel-Quad-Core_60038541335.html) the MeeGoPad T01 HDMI TV stick supports Ubuntu.

The MeeGoPad T01 HDMI TV stick comes with either 1GB RAM or 2GB RAM. Ubuntu 14.10 32-bit would be appropriate for the 2GB RAM model, so that you will have the most up-to-date software. Either Xubuntu 14.10 32-bit or Lubuntu 14.10 32-bit would be appropriate for the 1GB RAM model.

> Ubuntu 14.10 supports 3735F out of the box, just like the PC. Even the touch screen is supported out of the box, unlike the ARM platform to worry about the drivers, timing configuration, etc. I have to say UEFI is great.

A vanilla *buntu installation should work OK on the MeeGoPad T01 HDMI TV stick, if you have the model that came with Android preinstalled. If you have the model that came with Windows 8.1 preinstalled, you may have problems booting a different operating system due to the UEFI firmware and another possible issue is *will the UEFI firmware let you boot a 32-bit operating system?*. I haven't been able to find the answer to this question other than to try to boot a 32-bit operating system on the device, and see if it boots. The Intel Atom Z3735F "Bay Trail" quad core processor in your device supports both 32-bit and 64-bit operating systems, so you could install either a 32-bit or a 64-bit operating system on your device.

If that doesn't work, the next step would be to try and boot a small-sized 32-bit live USB like GParted live USB or Clonezilla live USB by plugging the live USB flash drive into the USB port on your device. If, for example, GParted live USB boots and Ubuntu doesn't boot, then you're ready to read this article [FAQ: Asus T100: Installing custom OS (android/ubuntu/*nix/Windows 7/Windows 8 x64)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2500078), which describes how to install a 64-bit OS along with a 32-bit bootloader on a UEFI firmware device.

One thing about the article that concerns me is that the author of the article assumes that if GParted live USB boots on your device it is because of the 32-bit architecture, but I have found this not to be the case. In my case older versions of Ubuntu will not boot, however Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit will boot, so I'm not convinced that the 32-bit architecture of the Ubuntu installation iso file has anything to do with it, but you won't know that for sure unless you try it out on your device.